Inline grids with open edges
I'm trying to make something like this, but with one of the edges being open (not drawn). Is that possible? Thanks.
For example, if I have this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=20pt, scale=0.5]
    \draw[ultra thick] (0, 0) grid (2, 3);
    \draw[ultra thick] (2, 1) rectangle (3, 2);
    \draw[ultra thick] (0, 0) rectangle (2, 3);
    \node at (1.5, 1.5) {\(s\)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

which produces this:

I want there not to be a line between (3,1) and (3,2).

Please clarify what you mean by "edge"; does it include the parentheses? -- And, which edge -- the one on the left, or the one on the right?

You can do it with tikz, with enough manual effort. I don't know how to parameterize it though. Basically, instead of using the grid and rectangle syntaxes, you'd just draw the lines yourself.

@Mico Sorry, I should've been more clear. I'm referring to the edges of the squares.

I suggest you create and add a mockup of what you are after to your question. Your code attempts will be highly valued, i.e. may speed up things ... Thank you

@MS-SPO Thanks, I've edited the question to include an example.

I just removed the problematic square, and drew its outline - minus the side in question.
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=20pt, scale=0.5]
    \draw[ultra thick] (0, 0) grid (2, 3);
    %\draw[ultra thick] (2, 1) rectangle (3, 2);
    \draw[ultra thick] (0, 0) rectangle (2, 3);
    \node at (1.5, 1.5) {\(s\)};

    % added
    \draw[ultra thick] (3,2) -- (2,2) -- (2,1) -- (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



That works. Thank you!
